# Solve a simultaneous equation with product of the 2 variables in Python?

Tags: python, equation-solving

If i have 2 equations:

```
x = ab
```

and

```
n = a+b
```

where x and n are known, and a and b are large whole numbers, how can I solve them using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a and b are the solutions of: X^2 - nX + x = 0

```
d = n*n - 4*x
a = (- b - d**0.5)/2
b = (- b + d**0.5)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import math
n = int(raw_input('What is the value of n?'))
x = int(raw_input('What is the value of x?'))
aEqu1 = (n + math.sqrt((n**2) - (4*x)))/2
bEqu2 = (n - math.sqrt((n**2) - (4*x)))/2

print "a equals ", aEqu1
print "b equals ", bEqu2
```

Comment: Thanks, mickNeill. This does work, but for small numbers. Instead of the math.sqrt , i used (...)**0.5, which did the trick